# advanced duplication detection & actions in dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm new to dynamics CRM, and I'm wondering if, and how, the following scenario can be supported:
When a record is created / updated, I want to be able to define how to find duplicate records.
If a duplicate is found, I want to be able to define automatic actions based on the new record's properties.

(for example- when a case is created, check for duplicate cases based on 'customer' and 'owner' fields. If a duplicate is found, then: if the duplicate case's status is not 'active' then go ahead and create a new record. otherwise- update some of the existing record's fields based on the new record).

The first part can easily be accomplished using duplication detection settings, but I don't think they allow for any complex logic when a duplicate is discovered.
The second part can easily be accomplished using workflows. however, I don't think that they offer conditions that check other records. I've looked into customizing workflows, but all I could find was how to customize *actions*, and not conditions.

Does dynamics CRM offer any solution to this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. You can accomplish this using CRM plugin. It should be Pre execution plug ins registered on Create and on Update events.